# How can I temporarily change the colour of some text?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a button that updates a Kendo UI Grid, all works fine. However I want to have some white text above the button that says "Changes saved" or something, not important.

How can I temporarily change the colour of some text?

I've looked into using `setTimeout()` but it seems like that executes a function *after* a set period of time, not *for* a set period of time. I know how to actually change the colour, using

```
document.getElementById("foo").style.color = "#ff0000";
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After realising that I'm stupid and missed an obvious way of doing this; this is how I did it.

```
var i = document.getElementById("alert");
i.style.color = "black";
setTimeout(function () { i.style.color = "white" }, 2000);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can still use setTimeout, just use it to change the color back

```js
document.getElementById("foo").style.color = "#ffff00";

setTimeout(function(){
document.getElementById("foo").style.color = "#ff0000";
},1500);
```

```html
<div id="foo">text</div>
```

Comment: Yeah I realised I could do this a few minutes after posting, thanks :)